# Any way to check anonymous functions?

Tags: php, function

Say that I have an array as follows:

```
array(
    [0] => function() { return "hello"; }
    [1] => function() { return "world"; }
    [2] => "look"
    [3] => function() { return "and";}
    [4] => function() { return "listen";}
)
```

Is there a way I can invoke 0, 1, 3 and 4 without invoking 2?

Comment: instanceof Closure && is_callable()

Comment: Wrote from phone, didn't want to do the formatting part. SO isn't mobile friendly. :(

Comment: Ah, too bad. Could have been best answer :)

Comment: I can make it an answer, but ThiefMaster has already it explained in detail. Why don't you accept his one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Anonymous functions are instances of the `Closure` class. So checking that and `is_callable` does the job.

```
foreach ($array as $func) {
    if (is_callable($func) && $func instanceof Closure) {
        $func();
    }
}
```

Actually, the class check should be enough since you cannot instantiate `Closure` objects manually except by creating an anonymous function.

Comment: @elite5472 did you test it? it should cause a fatal error if `"look"` is defined as a function because it will lead to testing `"look" instanceof Closure` which causes a fatal error. Lols, nevermind, that's just if you test a string directly instead of a variable containing a string... :D

Comment: Esailija, no, it leads to testing `$func instanceof Closure` which is valid: `$func = 'look'; var_dump($func instanceof Closure);` => `bool(false)`

Comment: That's not a WTF. From the manual: "instanceof is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class".

Comment: @EmilVikström then why does `new stdClass instanceof stdClass` work? There is no variable involved.

Comment: I don't know, that's not a documented usage.

Comment: They probably didn't think anyone would ever test the type of anything other than a variable, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: When I first saw this, I thought: "I remember phpman warned that Closure was just a temporary implementation detail" but the manual has been updated and it's considered ok to reply upon this detail. http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: What's the point of `is_callable()` before checking `Closure`?

Comment: I don't remember what made me write this 11 years ago ;) But based on my last sentence I guess its not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), it has [an undocument function to check for closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.isclosure.php); try this (haven't tested):

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $re = newReflectionFunction($val);
    if ($re->isClosure()) {
        $val();
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

...or check whether it isn't a string/numeric:

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!is_string($val) && !is_numeric($val)) {
        $val();
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

...or check whether it's an object:

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (gettype($val) == 'object') {
        $val();
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not very useful. What if it's not a string?

Comment: In your case it is, so I was assuming it was either an anonymous function or a string.

Comment: elite5472, that's not what you asked. From your question, a just as useful answer would be `if ($val !== 'look') ...`

Comment: @EmilVikström what if it changes dynamically?

Comment: @EmilVikström, I asked how to check anonymous functions, not how to check other types. It goes without saying that the type of whatever that isn't that is not what's important.

Comment: elite5472, here's your question: "Is there a way I can invoke 0, 1, 3 and 4 without invoking 2?". If you mean something different, say so!

Comment: Added another option using Reflection :)

Comment: @EmilVikström, that was an example. The actual question is clearly "Any way to check anonymous functions?"

Answer (score 1):

`gettype` on anon methods return "object" and `is_callable()` returns true on functions, then:

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (is_callable($val) && gettype($val)=="object") {
        $val();
    }
}
```

and here's my test code:

```
<?php 

function look(){
    return "looking";
}

$data=array(
    0 => function() { return "hello"; },
    1 => function() { return "world"; },
    2 => "look",
    3 => function() { return "and";},
    4 => function() { return "listen";}
);
echo "<pre>";

foreach ($data as $val) {
    if (is_callable($val) && gettype($val)=="object") {
        echo $val();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What if `look()` is a defined function?

Comment: THis isn't correct, because [__invoke](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)() exists and so any user defined object can be made callable.

Comment: Where is __invoke() in the question? Can string have __invoke()? In this case, this solution works. And thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. `$result` will be an array of the return value of each function call (except if it's not an anonymous function, in which case it will be the original value from `$array`).

```
$result = array_map(
                    function($e) {
                      return ($e instanceof Closure && is_callable($e)) ?
                        $e() : $e;
                    }, $array);
```